# Django JSONField query on a list of values where at least 1 value is in the filter list

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    genres = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=False, blank=False)
```

The data inside this column contains a list of genres e.g.:

```
["biography", "comedy", "crime", "drama", "romance"]
```

When I try and execute the following code, I get empty:

```
wanted_genres = ['action', 'adventure', 'animation', 'biography', 'comedy', 'crime', 'documentary', 'drama', 'family']

Movie.objects.all().distinct().filter(genres__contains = wanted_genres)
```

I want to get results where at least 1 genre of `wanted_genres` is found in the column genres. I have tried a lot of filter techniques but I can't find a good array to array comparison method. Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use contained_by instead of contains

```
Movie.objects.all().distinct().filter(genres__contained_by = wanted_genres)
```

For more information you can check [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contained-by)